# How to replace all the parameters?

Tags: r

Now I have a long function written by me and I want to change the character of the parameter. What is the easiest way to do that?

```
#For explanation 
func <- function(x,y){
           i <- x+5
           t <- x+y
           g <- y+95
           p <- i+t+g
           return(p)
           }
#I want to change all the parameter x to number and the result should be
func <- function(number,y){
           i <- number+5
           t <- number+y
           g <- y+95
           p <- i+t+g
           return(p)
           }
#How can I do it quickly instead of manual replace them one by one?
```

Comment: If you are working in RStudio as your IDE, select your long function, then just do a control+F or command+F if on a mac. In the find bar type x and in replace, type "number". Press All.

Comment: @Dhiraj thank you so much. It saves me a lot of time, thank you.

Comment: RStudio can even be smarter than that: select one occurence of the name of the variable, type ctrl - alt - shift - M, you'll get a multi-cursor on all occurences of the variable _in the right context_ (hence smarter) and then you can rename. To cancel the multi-cursor, you can press Esc or click somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work in the RStudio IDE, you can select one occurrence of the name of the variable, type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>, you'll get a multi-cursor on all occurrences of the variable in the right context (ie just in the body of the function for instance, which is what you want almost all of the time) and then you can rename.

To cancel the multi-cursor, you can press Esc or click somewhere else.